# Angular filter objects array for multiple values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following method that filters an object (that has an array of other objects) for an input field:

```
  filterArray(): void {
    this.json.items.filter((e) => e.assignedPool != null || e.assignedPool !== undefined);
    this.json.items = this.json.items.filter((e) => e.name.includes(this.filter));
  }
```

Now I want to filter for another variable. Here is the objecs hierarchie:

the filtered json variable:

```
export class VirtualServerResponse {
  private _kind: String;
  private _items: VirtualServer[];
```

a VirtualServer:

```
  //...properties
  private _assignedPool: PoolDTO;
```

a Pool:

```
  //properties
  private _membersReference: MembersReferenceDTO;
```

the membersReference:

```
export class MembersReferenceDTO {
  constructor() {}
  private _link: String;
  private _isSubcollection: String;
  private _items: PoolMemberDTO[];
```

and a single PoolMember:

```
export class PoolMemberDTO {
  constructor() {}
  private _address: String;
```

Now I want to be able to filter also for the address of a PoolMember, so when the `filter` matches an address of any PoolMember, something like

```
this.json.items.foreach((item) => 
item.assignedPool.membersReference.items.foreach(member) =>  
member.address == this.filter)
```

I want to filter the `json.items` array, so this array contains:

- all servers with name matching the filter
- all servers which assignedPool members addresses match the filter

Can someone help me here?

Update:

```
Server name: test server
Assigned pool -> membersReference ->items[]
items[0]: 10.10.10.2
items[1]: 10.10.10.3
```

...
So if the filter is 10.10.10.3, the server 'test server' should be in `json.items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check memberReference items to see if there is an address that matches the filter.

```
filterArray(): void {
  this.json.items = this.json.items.filter((e) => 
    (e.assignedPool !== null && e.assignedPool !== undefined)
    && (e.name.includes(this.filter) || e.assignedPool.membersReference.items.find((m) => m.address === this.filter));
}
```

Comment: No, it is simply a string

Comment: Try that. There is another filter for membersReference items to return if the address is equal to the filter. If that filter returns an array the same length as the original membersReference, all the addresses match the filter. Is the address and the name supposed to both be the same?

Comment: No, the name of a virtual server and the address of a pool are different, but searching for both of them is a major use case to mee:)

Comment: So you want to filter the server name to match this.filter. What do you want to match the address with?

Comment: match the filter too, in other words find the virtual server of a given pool members address

Comment: Can you give me an example of the this.filter, server name, and address?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187496/discussion-between-eric-svitok-and-itfreak).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your update, but now there is no filter for the name of a virtual server of json.items. I had all the solutions to filter on one on my own, but not for both :D

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your contribution, now it works!I only replaced the address=== filter with address.includes, but thats only a small change for more user-friendly behaviour